# Biblatex: Change date/year output for one literature-type only

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I have a book that uses footnotes and several bibliographies, and includes books, articles and the like. Ordinarily, the citation style author-year and along the lines of "Author (Year), Title, Publisher."
I use a code fragment to adapt the standard biblatex style so that I get parenthesis around the year for all literature types (see MWE). However, I have one literature type (misc2) that I created to cover court rulings (as misc one is used for legal documents that otherwise don't fit in the biblatex types). These are, unlike the rest, supposed to look like this: "EuG v. 15.6.2000, Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta" (Court v. Date, Title).

I want to adapt only the type misc 2 to show the year field in "v. YEAR" instead of "(YEAR)". How can I adapt my code for that purpose?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex
%command for generally putting parenthesis around year/date
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {\ifentrytype{misc}
    {
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        %\printtext[parens]{%
        %\printfield{labelyear}%
        %\printfield{extrayear}}
        }}  
    {
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printtext[parens]{%
        \printfield{labelyear}%
        \printfield{extrayear}}
        }}
   }
   }
\begin{document}

Test Document Group 1 (book)\autocite[2]{draftnotice}.


"Misc" is used for other legal documents, "Misc 2" is distinct and used for court rulings:


Test Document Group 2 (Misc2)\footnote{\fullcite{eugh29807}.} 


What Test Document Group 2 is supposed to be like\footnote{EuG v. 15.6.2000, Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta}

\end{document}
```

My lit.bib

```
@book{draftnotice,
    Author = {{Karl Marx}},
    Howpublished = {Capital},
    Year = {1867}}

@misc2{eugh29807,
    Author = {{EuG}},
    Howpublished = {Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta},
    Year = {15.6.2000}}
```

And a picture to show what i mean:

[image]

Comment: Please note that with `biblatex` the proper way to give a date with month and day is the `date` field: `date = {2000-06-15}` instead of `year = {15.6.2000}`. (You may need some modifications to show the full date in the correct format then.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareFieldFormat` for this, which allows formatting on a per-entry type. (I've changed your documentclass to `article`, since I don't have your class).

**Note:** This is a temporary answer, which although it works has some problems as noted in the comments. I will update with a better solution.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{draftnotice,
    Author = {{Karl Marx}},
    Howpublished = {Capital},
    Year = {1867}}

@misc2{eugh29807,
    Author = {{EuG}},
    Howpublished = {Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta},
    Year = {15.6.2000}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

%command for generally putting parenthesis around year/date
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
   \printtext[parens]{%
   \printfield{labelyear}%
   \printfield{extrayear}}%
   }}%
   }

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc2]{parens}{v. #1\addcomma}
\begin{document}

Test Document Group 1 (book)\autocite[2]{draftnotice}.


"Misc" is used for other legal documents, "Misc 2" is distinct and used for court rulings:


Test Document Group 2 (Misc2)\footnote{\fullcite{eugh29807}.} 


What Test Document Group 2 is supposed to be like\footnote{EuG v. 15.6.2000, Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of footnotes]

Comment: marvellous! seems to work.

Comment: The "risk" with this is that if the `parens` format is used anywhere else for `@misc2` one will still get the "v. " prefix, this could be undesirable. Introducing brackets in `cite:labelyear+extrayear` can cause double brackets in `\textcite` context.  (You might also want to make sure that the redefinition of `cite:labelyear+extrayear` does not introduce spurious spaces.)

Comment: @moewe Yes, I'm aware of that problem. I've fixed the spaces problem, but also adding the comma in the field format is problematic too.  Can you suggest a better way of solving this? (I can update my answer or feel free to add a new answer yourself.)

Comment: I didn't think of the `\addcomma` in the field format, but I agree that is also a bit unfortunate. I think the new format is sufficiently dissimilar that I would branch the entire cite macro with `\ifentrytype`. If I had to deal with legal citations I would probably create a new entry type for that and would be prepared to accept that the cite macro would look different for that special type.

Comment: I'll add an updated answer in a few days.